# array name change makes connection reset error

Tags: php

Why this PHP command generates CONNECTION RESET message in webbrowser:

```
$result[] = app::moveChildDown(dataaccessobject::instance()->getAll($sql,null,true));
```

and this doesn't:

```
$results[] = app::moveChildDown(dataaccessobject::instance()->getAll($sql,null,true));
```

Only change is from `$result[]` to `$results[]` - one sign, "s".

Could it be a server configuration issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is no *super configuration magic* regarding this. I guess that the variable `$result` was used before and is not an array. That's why pushing to it `[]=` will fail.

Try this:

```
$result   = array(); // reinitialize $result as empty array.
$result []= app::moveChildDown(dataaccessobject::instance()->getAll($sql,null,true));
```

Of course you'll have to find the real reason for having the variable name defined twice and find a solution.

Comment: It works!!!! Is it possible, that on server nr 1 it works without cleaning this array, and on another one array has to be cleared? I need to explain this to my client's server admin

Comment: I expect it to be defined in an if block and the if block is just entered on one of the servers. (for whatever reason). It's a typical example of: Don't define variables in an if block

Comment: I don't understand - could you explain it in other way?

Comment: Where have you defined `$results` the first time? Can you show the related code?

Comment: no, I can't - its huge app, I'm just trying to solve problem with search. 

I have an idea - is there a posibility, that on this serwer is a problem with adding elements to array? Is there any PHP/APACHE setting for this?

Comment: No setting! Its a problem with your code. Regualary this happens when a variable (`$result`) is defined in an `if` block or an other conditional statement.. On one server it enters the `if` on others not. Can you follow me?.

Comment: ok, but the problem is on production server and on test server everything works fine in the same condition (it's the search option, on both servers with the same parametrs) 
I'ts not my code - I'm just try to solve this problem.

Comment: But I guess it's not the same database.. ;). But the reason in any case is a programm error in the php code. no magic

Comment: How do you think - is there a posibility that, for example, diffrent version of PHP could be responsible for this? (on both servers)

Comment: :) I told it already three times to you: No magic, no version issues no apache problem. It is a bug in the PHP code. (Your application)